# Expo fastlane build fails due to issue with logging in EXUpdates / expo-updates

Tags: expo, eas, expo-updates

I get this error message when building an IOS app on an expo managed worfklow for SDK 46. The error appears at the end of the log, at line 716:  'Logger' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level. The expo-updates package is installed with the latest version (0.15.6).

The `expo doctor` command shows nothing wrong with the project.

```
Compiling expo-eas-client Pods/EASClient » EASClient-dummy.m

› Packaging expo-eas-client Pods/EASClient » libEASClient.a

› Executing expo-eas-client Pods/EASClient » Copy generated compatibility header

› Executing expo-updates Pods/EXUpdates » [CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates


❌  (node_modules/expo-updates/ios/EXUpdates/Logging/UpdatesLogger.swift:15:24)

  13 |   public static let EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY = "expo-updates"
  14 | 
> 15 |   private let logger = Logger(category: UpdatesLogger.EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY, options: [.logToOS, .logToFile])
     |                        ^ 'Logger' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
  16 | 
  17 |   // MARK: - Public logging functions
  18 | 


❌  (node_modules/expo-updates/ios/EXUpdates/Logging/UpdatesLogger.swift:15:91)

  13 |   public static let EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY = "expo-updates"
  14 | 
> 15 |   private let logger = Logger(category: UpdatesLogger.EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY, options: [.logToOS, .logToFile])
     |                                                                                           ^ extra argument 'options' in call
  16 | 
  17 |   // MARK: - Public logging functions
  18 | 


❌  (node_modules/expo-updates/ios/EXUpdates/Logging/UpdatesLogger.swift:15:93)

  13 |   public static let EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY = "expo-updates"
  14 | 
> 15 |   private let logger = Logger(category: UpdatesLogger.EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY, options: [.logToOS, .logToFile])
     |                                                                                             ^ reference to member 'logToOS' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
  16 | 
  17 |   // MARK: - Public logging functions
  18 | 


❌  (node_modules/expo-updates/ios/EXUpdates/Logging/UpdatesLogger.swift:15:103)

  13 |   public static let EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY = "expo-updates"
  14 | 
> 15 |   private let logger = Logger(category: UpdatesLogger.EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY, options: [.logToOS, .logToFile])
     |                                                                                                       ^ reference to member 'logToFile' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
  16 | 
  17 |   // MARK: - Public logging functions
  18 | 


❌  (node_modules/expo-updates/ios/EXUpdates/Logging/UpdatesLogReader.swift:15:32)

  13 | public class UpdatesLogReader: NSObject {
  14 |   private let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "dev.expo.updates.logging.reader")
> 15 |   private let logPersistence = PersistentFileLog(category: UpdatesLogger.EXPO_UPDATES_LOG_CATEGORY)
     |                                ^ cannot find 'PersistentFileLog' in scope
  16 | 
  17 |   /**
  18 |    Get expo-updates logs newer than the given date

▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

▸ The following build commands failed:

▸   CompileSwift normal arm64 (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')

▸   CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')

▸ (2 failures)

2023-01-06 08:55:22.238 xcodebuild[4410:14072] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

2023-01-06 08:55:22.238 xcodebuild[4410:14072] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

2023-01-06 08:55:22.327 xcodebuild[4410:14072] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}

2023-01-06 08:55:22.328 xcodebuild[4410:14072] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts

2023-01-06 08:55:22.328 xcodebuild[4410:14072] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!

2023-01-06 08:55:22.328 xcodebuild[4410:14072] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled as fontd is not available.

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

    CompileSwift normal arm64 (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')

    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')

(2 failures)

Exit status: 65

+-------------+-------------------------+

|           Build environment           |

+-------------+-------------------------+

| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |

| gym_version | 2.206.1                 |

| sdk         | iPhoneOS15.5.sdk        |

+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by upgrading to Expo SDK 47.